# Application settings lost on rebuild

Tags: plugins, nativescript, rebuild

Using the latest version of Nativescript and have some information stored in using the tns-core-modules/application-settings plugin.  Great these are settings that we need to persist.  However, it seems during development every time we end up rebuilding the application they are lost.  This typically occurs when we add a new plugin which causes a more complete rebuild.  This can also happen when we need to blow away the platforms folder as is unfortunately sometimes needed.

Is there any way to have this information persisted through these options.  We are trying to use this for login status and layout preferences.  Having to go through them every time a rebuild takes place sort of defeats the purpose.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open feature](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/3382) request already in the NativeScript CLI Github repo, you might want to vote and follow up there.